# Typo3 favicon for pdf File

Tags: typo3

i got an Website with Typo3 and i generated a favicon and put it online with typoscript. But when i open a pdf, that can be downloaded at my site, the standart typo3 icon appears. How can i change this?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a real ico (not png), name it favicon.ico and put it into your web root. Then load the ico via www.yourserver.com/favicon.ico and see if it works now.

Comment: do you want to post a link?

Comment: if you click on the .pdf Icon the Typo3 Favicon appears

Comment: Just looking at it from mobile yet. But replace http://ermuth-ermuth.de/favicon.ico with yours and you should be set

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a typo3-question.
The cache of favicons is very persistent. If you ever opened the download with the old favicon, in most cases, this issue appears.
Try to delete the whole browser cache, visit the page with an other browser or enable private browsing and try again.